# Is it possible to reuse mocks ?

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

I have a service ISOLanguageService with a method getDefaultLanguage();

I want to mock this service in one class ISOLanguageServiceMock in this way:

```
public class ISOLanguageServiceMock {

    @Mock
    private ISOLanguageService isoLanguageService;

    public ISOLanguageServiceMock() {

        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        ISOLanguage isoLanguage = new ISOLanguage();
        isoLanguage.setLanguageCode("EN");
        when(isoLanguageService.getDefaultLanguage()).thenReturn(isoLanguage);
    }
```

Then i have other service UserService that uses this service isoLanguageService in one of its metdhods.

```
public void doSomtthing() {
   return isoLanguageService.getDefaultLanguage()
}
```

I want to test the UserService but i want in someway to reuse the mock ISOLanguageServiceMock because it's going to be used in many other services.

I want Something like this

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class UserServiceTest {

    private ISOLanguageServiceMock languageMock = new ISOLanguageServiceMock();

    @InjectMocks
    private UserService userService;

    public void setUp() {
       MockitoAnnotations.init(this) 

    }

    public void testDoSomething() {

        userService.doDomething();
    }

}
```

I'd like that the mock for isoLanguageService be injected in the userService, but it's not...

Is there anyway to reuse a mocks ?? Do i have to write in every test class the mock for isoLanguageService ??

Answer (score 1):

You can't reuse mocks this way. You need `@Mock` instances to be **in** your test case, and use them there.

Meaning:

```
@Mock
private ISOLanguageService isoLanguageService;
```

and specifications for into your `UserServiceTest` class.

Mockito does not understand (or care) that your ISOLanguageServiceMock class contains something that could be injected into the class under test. 
Mockito looks for the mocks you have in your test class, and those get injected, nothing else!

Regarding the re-use aspect:

- you could do that by subclassing (having a base class with that @Mock field)
- but then, that is bad practice, to a certain degree. Unit tests should be self contained, as much as possible. It is *okay* when unit tests duplicate code, because you want to be able to look at **one** file (your test case) to understand what is going on).

Meaning: (in general), code duplication within unit tests isn't that crucial. The goal of unit tests is to enable quick debugging.

Well, some alternatives:

- you can of course, not use `@InjectMocks`. In that case, your production code needs another way for you to inject mocked objects yourself (either setters, or test only constructors).
- when you inject manually, you can of course inject whatever mock object you want to, even one that comes from another class
- but then: no extra class required, simply have a `static` method somewhere that returns a (pre-configured) mock.

Comment: Yes, i know i should @Mock isoLanguageService in UserServiceTest. But how can i reuse the functionality mocked in other test without writting it again ?

Comment: Well, my UserService don't have setters for isoLanguageService. They are @Injected in the declaration. How does MockitoAnnotations inject the mocks when there are no setters ?

Comment: @FernandoGuardiola It uses reflection. Which makes it cool on the one side, but annoying, as it doesn't tell you when it is failing.

Comment: But with reflection is it possible to call a set method that is not defined? With reflection is it possible to set/read a property without setter/getter?

Comment: With reflection it is possible to access private fields. What Mockito does is to *check* via reflection if there are fields that match the type of mocked objects it sees. Its like: "OK, I found a mocked potato, and an egg, now lets see if the target class could make use of that potato or egg".

Comment: @FernandoGuardiola And just saying: I already spent quite some time providing an in depth answer. The only thing that comes back from you ... more question. That is not how SO is supposed to work. We dont play more-questions-via-comments ping pong here.